# Python csv writer outputs commas after each letter

Tags: python, csv, writer

My csv file has nothing but commas after every letter. It writes the data to a newline. What am I doing wrong with the data? I am trying to write each address to a new line in csv after it is put into a list. I have tried all kinds of different methods to write the data to a csv file but nothing has worked. I can't figure out what to do to make the data write the name and not so many commas.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

search_terms = "Bars"
location = "New Orleans, LA"
all_data = []

if ' ' in search_terms:
    search_terms = search_terms.replace(' ', '+')
    print(search_terms)
if ', ' in location:
    location = location.replace(', ', '+')
    print(location)
count = 1

while True:
    page_number = str(count)
    url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search? search_terms="+search_terms+"&geo_location_terms="+location+"&page="+page_number
    print(url)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    info = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "info"})
    if soup.findAll("div", {"class": "info"}):
        count = count+1
        for each in info:
            try:
                business_name = each.find(itemprop="name").get_text()
            except:
                business_name = "No Business Name"
            try:
                street = each.find(itemprop="streetAddress").get_text()
            except:
                street = "No Street Address"
            try:
                city = each.find(itemprop="addressLocality").get_text()
            except:
                city = "No City,"
            try:
                state = each.find(itemprop="addressRegion").get_text()
            except:
                state = "No State"
            try:
                zip = each.find(itemprop="postalCode").get_text()
            except:
                zip = "No Zip Code"
            try:
                telephone = each.find(itemprop="telephone").get_text()
            except:
                telephone = "No Telephone"
            business_data = business_name+","+street+","+city+state+","+zip+","+telephone
            business_data = business_data.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
            all_data.append(business_data)
    else:
        break
with open(search_terms+'.csv', 'w+') as wf:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(wf)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Business Name","Street Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Telephone"])
    for line in all_data:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
        print(line)
```

Comment: Do you have a **minimal** [mcve]? This should be reproducible in approximately 5 lines.

Comment: Notice that `line` is a string and `csv_writer.writerow` expects a list, so it breaks your string to array of chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writerow method expects an iterable consisting of all the items of the row. As you are passing it a string, it will iterate over each character and consider each as an item.

To instead go over the fields, instead of

```
business_data = business_name+","+street+","+city+state+","+zip+","+telephone
all_data.append(business_data)
```

You may want to try something like

```
all_data.append([business_name, street, city + state, zip, telephone])
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`all_data.append(business_data)`
appends one string to all_data,
so `csv_writer.writerow(line)` has `line` as a string, while it expect `list`.
Try:

```
for line in all_data:
        array = line.split(',')
        csv_writer.writerow(array)
        print(line)
```